# SQLAlchemy group_by where select differs from aggregate target

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, group-by, sqlalchemy

I'm struggling to write an aggregating GROUP BY query with SQL Alchemy that returns the result of aggregating over a table "lower down" and a joined entity "higher up" which happens to be the grouping key, instead of returning the aggregating entity, e.g.:

```
qry = session.query(PSU, func.count(PSU.id)).join(PSU).join(StockUnit).join(Part).group_by(Part)
```

but I want to return (Part, the_count), not (PSU, the_count). Writing `session.query(Part, func.count(...))` queries the wrong way round.

Here is the SQL I want query using SQL Alchemy semantics:

```
select 
  psu.package_id,
  p.*,            -- the joined entity
  count(psu.*)    -- the aggregate
from packaged_stock_unit psu
inner join stock_unit su
 on su.id = psu.stock_unit_id
inner join part p
 on p.id = su.part_id
where
 psu.some_value = 1
 and psu.package_id = 1
group by psu.package_id, p.sku;
```

Perhaps this is possible with the SQLAlchemy base functions?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`select_from()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from) to control the "left" side of the join in case you need it:

```
qry = session.query(Part, func.count(PSU.id)).\
    select_from(PSU).\
    join(StockUnit).\
    join(Part).\
    group_by(Part)
```